# Class log does not exist in F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738 Stack trace:

Tags: laravel-5

I ran `config:cache` in my Laravel 5.2 application and this error started showing up.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738): ReflectionClass->__construct('log') #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array) #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array) #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(853): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log') #4 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(808): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter)) #5 F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(7 in F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 738

I looked for many solutions. Nothing worked for me.

- My `.env` file does not have any spaces
- I deleted extra packages from my `composer.json` and ran `composer update`.
- I ran `php artisan clear` compiled many times.
- I looked for errors in my files but could not find any.
- I also enabled the `mysql` extension since I found it somewhere. Then I did a fresh checkout of Laravel 5.2 and now the error is like this.

[image]

So, it's not a problem of any config file of mine. Its something else. Any of you have any idea?

Comment: check your config file, have you edited any config file?

Comment: +Nehal Hasnayeen I have , but I checked them and did not really find any error. Is there a sure shot way to find out?By running some command or code?

Comment: show the code you changed , there is no command to find out, you can use echo or dd() method to check the line where the error has been thrown

Comment: +Nehal Hasnayeen .. I edited my question because I found something about the problem. I am requesting you to read it please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok , so I solved it. Looks liek I had multiple issues.

- In my fresh check out of laravel 5.2, where I was finding error about not having vendor/autoload.php file, I ran in the root directory in command window,

> 'composer update --no-scripts' , then 'composer update'. That solved the issue.

- I also had to enable my mysql extension by editing php.ini file.
- Finally, in my existing project, I actually found a problem in config/app.php. I missed a ',' somewhere. And people, laravel is a disgusting debugger. I miss my cakephp more.

**It's a laravel 5 issue. Better to use laravel 4 still**

Comment: Pretty bold statement given it's based on testing stuff with XAMPP on Windows which is known to be easily broken. I'd suggest migrating to more reliable and proven solutions like Vagrant (https://www.vagrantup.com/) combined with a provisioning tool like (https://puphpet.com/) which will make sure your testing environment meets all the dependency requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

then `composer update`

Comment: i already answered it long back.this is not he answer. i tried it that time.please read mine